# I it possible to recover a USB with game files formatted when plugged into a different Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, technical-issues

A friend had been saving games on his Xbox 360 using a USB drive. He moved it to a different Xbox 360 and it reformatted the USB for use, deleting his files. I suggested he used some data recovery software, but then it turns out the `.svg` saved game files aren't visible on Windows.

I wasn't able to find anything concrete on Google, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your friend used a data recovery software, but that software didn't find any `.svg` files? Did it find *anything* at all?

Comment: This question might be better asked on a different stackexchange site. But here's a link to some software that might help you. http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9224577/6_data_recovery_tools_for_SD_cards_USB_drives_and_more